# Send E-Mail in Flutter (Firebase Backend)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-extensions

I am creating my person website using Flutter-Web. I am using Firebase as back-end and will host the website on Firebase.
In my contact me page I have created a form with the following details

1. Name
2. E-Mail
3. Subject
4. Message

I want to send this details to me via email and send the same details to email that was entered in E-Mail field

I planned to use https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email extension to send email.

Bellow is snippet for brief description.

> **How this extension works**
>
> Use this extension to render and send emails that contain the
> information from documents added to a specified Cloud Firestore
> collection.
>
> Adding a document triggers this extension to send an email built from
> the document's fields. The document's top-level fields specify the
> email sender and recipients, including to, cc, and bcc options (each
> supporting UIDs). The document's message field specifies the other
> email elements, like subject line and email body (either plaintext or
> HTML)

My understanding is that I need to save the data in Firestore collection to trigger email. Am I getting it correct? 
If so is their any way I can send an email without storing in Firestore collection for this particular extension? 
If no what alternatives are available to me.
As this is a personal site cost of such service will be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that I need to save the data in Firestore collection to trigger email. Am I getting it correct?

Yes, that is correct.

> If so is their [sic] any way I can send an email without storing in Firestore collection for this particular extension?

No. This extension specific sends an email when a document is written to Firestore. It does nothing when no document is written to Firestore.

> If no what alternatives are available to me[?]

Product recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but search is probably your best friend here since you're looking for [how to send an email from a Flutter app](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+send+an+email+from+a+Flutter+app) or a [free service for sending email from your Flutter app](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+service+for+sending+email+from+your+Flutter+app).